# What title can be used in opposition of "Diseases of Attitude"?

Tags: antonyms, titles

I've been recently asked to watch a video titled "[Diseases of Attitude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sG31mTbHJU&t=336s)". It's essentially a metaphor for people with attitude problems.

I'm intrigued to make an opposing title, such as "Wonders of Attitude", but that just doesn't seem to work as the opposite of "Diseases" in this context.

What title can be used in the sentence "____ of Attitude" which is the exact opposite of "Diseases of Attitude" in its same context?

Comment: What are some examples at each end? What are the characteristics you are trying to highlight at the ‘good’ end?

Comment: How about "powers"?

Comment: Why not, "The modesty of attitude..."? A little different!

Answer (score 1):

How about **upsides** or **benefits** or **advantages**? From Lexico:

> **[upside](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/upside)**: The positive or favorable aspect of something.

> **[benefit](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/benefit)**: An advantage or profit gained from something.

> **[advantage](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/advantage)**: A favorable or desirable circumstance or feature; a benefit.

Your "diseases of attitude" focuses on the negative aspects of attitude. **Upsides** *of attitude*, **benefits** *of attitude*, **advantages** *of attitude* do the opposite.

Comment: Good answer. It’s hard to find an antonym to *diseases* that strikes the right tone. *Benefits* is a nice choice. I actually liked *wellments* better, but I fear it would be lost on most people. I upvoted both of you.

Comment: @GlobalCharm  Thanks. **Benefits** was the first word that came to mind. *Wellment* is interesting, but it’s not a word in Lexico, Merriam-Webster, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more alliterative (it sounds more like "diseases"), how about **Successes of Attitude**?  Plus I think more apt for the video in question, which gives a laundry list of attitudes to avoid (indifference, pessimism, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest : Wellments of Attitude

as a wordplay on "ailments".

Given as the purpose of the lecture is to highlight several "dispositions of the mind" ( indifference, indecision, doubt, overcaution, complaining ), so to speak, to which the mind of most individuals falls prey, preventing them from self-fulfilment, it seems only right to me that wellness should be opposed to the illness of being impaired from such diseases.

You may object, though, that it is customary that "the stems to which -ment is normally appended are those of verbs" - to quote Henry Watson Fowler.

Comment: Triumphs or Successes of Attitude.

Comment: @Xanne The way I see it, your suggestions miss the mark, as triumphs or successes are the results of an attitude, whereas diseases result in a negative attitude, are a negative attitude even, with accompanying symptoms and illness.
The right opposite would therefore be something resulting in / being a positive attitude, in my opinion.